# Differentiating different sets in an or statement?

Tags: meaning

"Available to U.S. citizens or permanent residents of the United States that have been medically determined to have a permanent disability"

In the above statement (a cookie to those who can guess where that came from), if one were to read it
with no context -- what would the correct interpretation?

1. It is available to the set of {U.S. Citizens} or the set of {permanent residents of the U.S. that have a disability}.
2. It is available to the set of {U.S. Citizens or Permanent residents of the U.S.} either of which have a permanent disability.

How would one go about "fixing" the statement to be more clear in either interpretations?

Comment: I vote for interpretation 2. I might fix it by saying "It is available to those who have been medically determined to have a permanent disability, whether US Citizens or permanent residents of the United States."

Comment: That cookie thing is so cute!